# SQL getting SUM of column

Tags: php, sql, variables, sum, coldfusion

SELECT SUM(total_cost)
FROM purchase;

How do I make the value of SUM(total_cost) to a variable?
If SUM(total_cost) = 300, how do I assign 300 to $result for example?
I'm trying to do this in coldfusion, but php will work too.

Comment: dont you just go  $result =SELECT SUM(total_cost)FROM purchase;  in php??

Comment: What was wrong with the answer you marked correct for this very question 8 days ago?

Answer (score 0):

> You can completely handle it in the MySQL query:

```
SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

Using PDO (`mysql_query` is deprecated)

```
$stmt = $handler->prepare('SELECT SUM(value) AS value_sum FROM codes');
$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$sum = $row['value_sum'];
```

Or using mysqli:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT SUM(value) AS value_sum FROM codes'); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
$sum = $row['value_sum'];
```

Answer (score 0):

For mysqli

```
$data   = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT SUM(value) AS value_sum FROM codes'); 
$row    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data); 
$result = $row['value_sum'];
```

Now u can get a Sum of value in $result